Behavior of ffmpeg when recording a stream and then network does not work for a while
I think it would be good, if ffmpeg would exit with error, if it finds out that network is not working and it thus can not record the given URL. But in my experience it just leaves there and can not continue recording even if network starts working again. I am using ffmpeg 4.4.2. Maybe newer version can handle network breakdown better?
Note: Even with the version that I use if exits with error "Invalid data found when processing input" if network is not working when recording starts.
I am using this kind of command to record:
    ffmpeg -hide_banner -i "$stream" -c copy \
    -t "$time"  -f stream_segment -segment_time "$segment_time" \
    -segment_atclocktime 1 -reset_timestamps 1 -strftime 1 \
    -segment_format "$container"  \
    "$output_path"'-%FT%H%M%z'"$filename_extension" \

Workarounds and fixes welcome. Maybe there is a better tool for recording?

What's the command line you're using?

@ChrisDavies see the updated post

I have created a ticket about the issue years ago https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/9206
